# Greedy algorithm for finding a negafibonacci representation of a number?

Tags: algorithm, math, fibonacci, greedy, decomposition

According to [Zeckendorf's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeckendorf's_theorem), every positive integer can be written in a unique way as the sum of non-consecutive distinct Fibonacci numbers. Such a decomposition can be found easily with a greedy algorithm consisting essentially in subtracting the largest Fibonacci number that fits and iterating, for example:

`20 = 13 + 7 = 13 + 5 + 2`

However, the theorem also implies that any integer (also <= 0) has a unique decomposition as a sum of distinct, non-consecutive negaFibonacci numbers, that is the sequence

0, 1, -1, 2, -3, 5, -8, ...

or F_(-n) = (-1)^(n+1) F_n. Some examples:

`-4 = - 3 - 1`

`4 = 5 + 1`

`11 = 13 - 3 + 1`

Is there a known easy algorithm for decomposing a given integer in this way?

Comment: See also: [NegaFibonacci representation for n](http://oeis.org/A215022), [NegaFibonacci representation for -n](http://oeis.org/A215023)

Comment: Woops, fixed the typo in the example. Thank you, I did not notice the OEIS had those few lines of code.

Comment: Amazing question. This was a ton of fun to work through!

Answer (score 4):

There is a nice greedy algorithm you can use to represent numbers in negafibonacci.

The idea behind this algorithm is to split the integers into ranges delimited by pairs of even Fibonacci numbers (in the positive case) and odd Fibonacci numbers (in the negative case). Specifically, we'll split the positive numbers into the ranges

- F<sub>0</sub> + 1 to F<sub>2</sub>, inclusive,
- F<sub>2</sub> + 1 to F<sub>4</sub>, inclusive,
- F<sub>4</sub> + 1 to F<sub>6</sub>, inclusive,
- F<sub>6</sub> + 1 to F<sub>8</sub>, inclusive,
- F<sub>8</sub> + 1 to F<sub>10</sub>, inclusive,
- ...
- F<sub>2k</sub> + 1 to F<sub>2k+2</sub>, inclusive,
- ...

We'll similarly split the n numbers into these ranges demarcated by negative Fibonacci numbers:

- -F<sub>1</sub> to -F<sub>3</sub> + 1, inclusive,
- -F<sub>3</sub> to -F<sub>5</sub> + 1, inclusive,
- -F<sub>5</sub> to -F<sub>7</sub> + 1, inclusive,
- -F<sub>7</sub> to -F<sub>9</sub> + 1, inclusive,
- ...
- -F<sub>2k-1</sub> to -F<sub>2k+1</sub> + 1, inclusive,
- ...

The greedy algorithm then proceeds as follows:

- If the number is positive, find the range [F<sub>2k</sub> + 1, F<sub>2k+2</sub>] containing n, add F<sub>2k+1</sub> to the representation, and subtract F<sub>2k+1</sub> from n.
- If the number is negative, find the range [-F<sub>2k-1</sub>, -F<sub>2k+1</sub> + 1] containing n, add -F<sub>2k</sub> to the representation, and add F<sub>2k</sub> to the total.
- If the number is zero, you're done.

Let's do an example. Suppose I want to convert 27 into negafibonacci. I find that 21 + 1 ≤ 27 ≤ 55. This sandwiches the (odd-index) Fibonacci number 34, so I add 34 to the total and then try to convert 27 - 34 = -7 into negafibonacci.

Next, we notice that 5 + 1 ≤ 7 ≤ 13, so 7 is sandwiched in a range containing the (even-indexed) Fibonacci number 8. We therefore add -8 into the total and try to convert 1 to negafibonacci.

Now, we notice that 0 + 1 ≤ 1 ≤ 1, so 1 is sandwiched in a range containing the (odd-indexed) Fibonacci number 1. We therefore add 1 into the total and try to convert 0 to negafibonacci.

This leaves a total of 0, so we're done! And hey! 34 - 8 + 1 = 27.

Let's first argue correctness. First, notice that if we add in a positive Fibonacci number, it must be an odd-numbered Fibonacci number (since we pick something of the form F<sub>2k+1</sub>), and if we add in a negative Fibonacci number, it must be a negative even-numbered Fibonacci number (since we pick something of the form -F<sub>2k</sub>). So each number added in will have the proper sign.

Next, we'll prove termination. Look at the positive case first. If we find that we have a number in the range [F<sub>2k</sub> + 1, F<sub>2k+2</sub>], then we subtract out F<sub>2k+1</sub>. The upper bound on the number is then F<sub>2k+2</sub> - F<sub>2k+1</sub> = F<sub>2k</sub>, so the largest interval containing the remainder will fall in the range [F<sub>2k-2</sub> + 1, F<sub>2k</sub>] and the highest Fibonacci number we could pull out would be F<sub>2k-1</sub>. Therefore, we can't repeat the Fibonacci number we previously removed, and there will be a gap between the positive numbers pulled out.

The lower bound on the number is F<sub>2k</sub> + 1 - F<sub>2k+1</sub> = -F<sub>2k-1</sub> + 1. That means that if the number is negative, the "highest" negative interval containing it would be [F<sub>2k-1</sub> + 1, F<sub>2k-3</sub>], so the highest negative Fibonacci number we could pull out is F<sub>2k-2</sub>. Therefore, we will pull out a lower-order Fibonacci number.

We can do similar math to show that pulling out a negative Fibonacci number shifts our window down one step.

To implement this efficiently, we can keep track of three consecutive Fibonacci numbers (F<sub>k-1</sub>, F<sub>k</sub>, F<sub>k+1</sub>) and keep shifting it upward (or downward) until we find a range containing the number n. We can then pull out our (possibly negative) Fibonacci number and then shift the window back toward 0 until we're done. Overall, this will run in time O(log n).

Comment: Shouldn't the complexity for the suggested implementation be O(log^2 n)? Pulling out each number takes O(log n), and there can be O(log n) such pull outs. Am I missing something?

Comment: That's one way to do it, but since you know the Fibonacci numbers you'll be pulling out are decreasing, you can do O(log n) initial work to find the first one, then keep stepping back one Fibonacci number at a time to extract the remaining ones. The total work to find all the others is then O(log n).